# Store data with Laravel as API with ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this code at index.blade :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    New Task
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!-- Display Validation Errors -->
                    @include('common.errors')

                    <!-- New Task Form -->
                    <form action="/task" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <!-- Task Name -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="task-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task</label>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="task-name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('task') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Add Task Button -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i>Add Task
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Current Tasks -->
            @if (count($tasks) > 0)
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Current Tasks
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-striped task-table">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Task</th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($tasks as $task)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-text"><div>{{ $task->name }}</div></td>

                                        <!-- Task Delete Button -->
                                        <td class="text-right">
                                            <form action="/task/{{ $task->id }}" method="POST">
                                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                                                <button type="submit" id="delete-task-{{ $task->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>Delete
                                                </button>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    </div>
    </div>
```

And this work well... 
NOW - Just for fun I try to STORE data with jquery ajax so i write function dodaj() :

```
function dodaj(){

            var name = 'JASAMBRE';

            $.ajax({
                url: "/store",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    name: name
                },
                dataType: "html",

                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log('GRESKA NEKA');
                }


            });
        }
```

Now when i run function from browser I get `500 Internal Server error`.

I now that I must send my authentification data but how I can STORE data with jquery ajax?

**UPDATE:**   I try:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

            if (token) {
                return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token);
            }
        });
        function dodaj(){

            var name = 'JASAMBRE';

            $.ajax({
                url: "/store",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

                    if (token) {
                        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token);
                    }
                },
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    name: name
                },
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log('GRESKA NEKA');
                }


            });
        }
```

Comment: The obvious problem here is that you're not passing the [CSRF token](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection). Read [this article](https://www.yesdevnull.net/2015/02/using-x-xsrf-token-http-headers-for-ajax-in-laravel-5/).

Comment: Can you write some example how I can pass CSRF token with ajax?

Comment: That's what the linked article explains.

Comment: I try: function dodaj(){

   var name = 'JASAMBRE';
   $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

    if (token) {
     return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token);
    }
   });
   $.ajax({
    url: "/store",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

     if (token) {
      return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token);
     }
    },
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: {
     name: name
    },
    but again is the same ERROR  - 500...

Comment: Please edit the question and replace the old code with the new one you tried, because pasted in the comments it's unreadable.

Comment: ok, i update question

Comment: You must also add the meta tag that holds the token value in the `<head>` section from you `layouts.app` view file:  `<meta name="csrf_token" ="{{ csrf_token() }}">`.

Comment: Again is the same: http://i.imgur.com/QtF94Sy.png and yes Now I have scrf token at head tag: <meta name="csrf_token" ="3zdsx4d5ngyehyvewkst1bye8yrpnn9334e6xt">

Comment: Check your error log in `storage/logs/laravel.log` to what's the error.

Comment: [2015-12-07 23:48:52] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\wamp\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1  ETC... ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using csrf_field(), it creates a hidden field with the name "_token" you can verify it by using the "view source code" feature on your browser.
Anyway what you can do is to get this field's value and append it to your data when doing the HTTP request.

```
// knowing that this field exists
var token = document.getElementsByName('_token')[0].value;
$.ajax({
  url: '/task',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
     name: name,
     _token: token
  },
  ...      
});
```

Comment: My bad, change url to '/task'

Comment: Yes that work for me :) But is there any security holes and problem when I add data at this way ? And why /task - Why not /store ?

Comment: First it worked with '/task' because your first form's action was set to '/task'.

Comment: There is no problem using the csrf token this way, you can do a bit of code to include it on all your ajax request. Something that can become on a security hole is to disable csrf middleware. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer ;)

Comment: offcource that is correct answer... I also try to make a function for delete request and I write: function brisi(id){

   var id = id;
   var token = document.getElementsByName('_token')[0].value;
   $.ajax({
    url: '/task/'+id,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
     
     _token: token
    }
   });
  } But I get 405 error - method not allowed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97242/discussion-between-sergio-guillen-mantilla-and-monkeybusiness).